# Can I map a function over a sequence of arguments without making the arguments into a list first?

Tags: pattern-matching, syntax, expression-manipulation

I would like to set

```
evenFunction[f_][a_, b_, c_, ...] = f[Abs[a], Abs[b], Abs[c], ...]
```

I have come up with two ways to do this so far.

1. Use pure functions

   ```
   evenFunction = Function[{f}, f[Sequence @@ Abs[{##}]] &]
   ```
2. Use pattern matching

   ```
   evenFunction[f_][x__] := f[Sequence @@ (Abs[{x}])]
   ```

What is bothering me is that, in both cases, I first have to turn the arguments into a list, and then back to a sequence. Is there a way without this?

Comment: `evenFunction[f_][x__] := f @@ Abs[{x}]` is a bit simpler.

Comment: Simply evenFunction[f_][x__] := Abs /@ f[x] would work if Map held its arguments unevaluated

Comment: I like @Szabolcs's answer the best, but you could always force the unevaluation using `evenFunction[f_][a__] := ReleaseHold@Map[Abs, Hold@f@a, {2}]`. I don't think there's any reason why you would do this instead though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the following meets your formal requirements

```
evenFunction[f_][args__] := f[Abs /@ Unevaluated[args]]

evenFunction[even][a, b, c]
```

> ```
> even[Abs[a], Abs[b], Abs[c]]
> ```

But is it really better than

```
evenFunction[f_][args__] := f @@ Abs[{args}]
```

I, myself, would choose the 2nd version over the 1st.

#### Update

It is not necessary to set the attribute `SequenceHold` as I originally did.